# The argument type 'bool' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FormzSubmissionStatus?'

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement form validation using the Formz package but I'm getting the above error on my controller, I can't seem to figure it out. Please anybody knows a fix for this? Help me!! The error is coming from the  "status: Formz.validate([])"

```
import 'package:flymedia_app/src/auth/signup/controller/signup_state.dart';
import 'package:form_validators/form_validators.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class SignupController extends StateNotifier<SignUpState> {
  SignupController() : super(const SignUpState());

  void onNameChange(String value) {
    final name =  Name.dirty(value);
    state = state.copyWith(
      name: name,
      status: Formz.validate([
        name,
        state.email,
        state.password,
      ]),
    );
  }



  void signUpWithEmailAndPassword() async {
    if (!state.status.isValidated)  return;
      print('Signing up...');
  }

}
```

Also here "if (!state.status.isValidated)  return;" I'm getting "The getter 'isValidated' isn't defined for the type 'FormzSubmissionStatus'."

This is my Signup State
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:form_validators/form_validators.dart';

```
class SignUpState extends Equatable {
  final Name name;
  final Email email;
  final Password password;
  final FormzSubmissionStatus status;
  final String? errorMessage;

  const SignUpState({
    this.name = const Name.pure(),
    this.email = const Email.pure(),
    this.password = const Password.pure(),
    this.status = FormzSubmissionStatus.initial,
    this.errorMessage,
  });

  SignUpState copyWith({
    Name? name,
    Email? email,
    Password? password,
    FormzSubmissionStatus? status,
    String? errorMessage,
  }) {
    return SignUpState(
      name: name ?? this.name,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      password: password ?? this.password,
      status: status ?? this.status,
      errorMessage: errorMessage ?? this.errorMessage,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props =>
      [
        name,
        email,
        password,
        status,
      ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed with types. `Formz.validate` returns `bool`, but your status field is `FormzSubmissionStatus enum`. So you have to change it's type, or add another field, for example `isValid` and assign `Formz.validate` result to it.